# acts_as_votable database model not present in Rails console but is available in PgAadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, pg, rails-models, acts-as-votable

I am using the [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) gem in my project. For some odd reasons I cannot access the `Vote` model table in `Rails console`. I reloaded my `development` environment and even restarted my computer.

I am able to `upvote` a model and `get_upvotes.size` of voted model.

I want to do some specialized query e.g. `Vote.where(...)`. when I tried to query for `Vote.all` in my rails console I get an error. By the way I am using postgresql for development.

```
2.0.0-p353 :007 > Vote.all
NameError: uninitialized constant Vote
```

The `Vote` model is present in my `schema.rb` but not in `app/models`. The `Vote` table is present in pgAdmin. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Vote` model is defined within the `ActsAsVotable` module. To use it outside an acts_as_votable model use:

```
ActsAsVotable::Vote.all
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks